# Construct SQL Statement to retrieve count() of specific records in same/different table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I did previously ask a question about this, but must admit was biased against SQL based solutions and now I can't find the question, so I'll try again, phrase it carefully and be much more open to any solutions provided.

I have two tables:

```
tblCurrent 
 Ref  | CustomerID | ... .. .. .  . |
X001
X002
X003


tblHistorical 
 Ref   | ... .. .. .  . |  Missing | Matched
X001   | ... .. .. .  . |  TRUE    | FALSE
X001   | ... .. .. .  . |  FALSE   | FALSE
X002   | ... .. .. .  . |  TRUE    | TRUE
X002   | ... .. .. .  . |  TRUE    | FALSE
X003   | ... .. .. .  . |  FALSE   | FALSE
X003   | ... .. .. .  . |  TRUE    | TRUE
```

Ref is unique in tblCurrent, but not in Historical.

How can I construct a view, that is based on tblCurrent that results in three additional columns that count the number of records in tblHistorical that:

- match the Ref AND Missing is TRUE
- match the Ref AND Missing is False
- match the Ref AND Matched is True

Note that I will need to add additional columns that count the number of records in tblHistorical based on similar criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use `LEFT JOIN` on this since it is possible that sometime `ref` may not exist on `tblHistorical` table.

```
SELECT  a.ref,
        SUM(CASE WHEN b.Missing = 'True' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) missingTrue,
        SUM(CASE WHEN b.Missing = 'False' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) missingFalse,
        SUM(CASE WHEN b.Matched = 'True' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) matchTrue
FROM    tblCurrent a
        LEFT JOIN tblHistorical b
            on a.ref = b.ref
GROUP BY a.ref
```

Comment: Good thinking, you would be correct in your assumption.  The last time I saw this kind of SQL I just saw random rubbish, now it seems somewhat clearer, LMAO.  Thanks to everyone's input.

Comment: John, how would I then be able to add a column to the view that counts the number of records in the tblCurrent table for the same CustomerID???

Comment: COUNT(customerID).. Is that what you want?

Comment: No, because if I just add "Count(CustomerID)" it will count all records.  For each record I want it to count the number of other records that match that CustomerID (and some other criteria to make it a little bit more fun)

Comment: Oops sorry my bad, remember that you are grouping the records by a.ref, how can you count the customers if each ref has one and only one customerid? F you really want that where would you display the count of the customer?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT R.Ref,
SUM(CASE WHEN H.Missing = TRUE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as MissingTrue,
SUM(CASE WHEN H.Missing = FALSE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as MissingFalse,
SUM(CASE WHEN H.Matched = TRUE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as MatchedTrue
FROM tblRef R JOIN tblHistorical H
ON R.Ref = H.Ref
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT R.Ref,
SUM(CASE WHEN H.Missing = TRUE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as MissingTrue,
SUM(CASE WHEN H.Missing = FALSE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as MissingFalse,
SUM(CASE WHEN H.Matched = TRUE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as MatchedTrue
FROM tblRef R 
INNER JOIN tblHistorical H
ON R.Ref = H.Ref
Group by R.Ref
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT T.REF,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN H.MISSING = 'TRUE' THEN 1  END) AS MISSINGTRUE,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN H.MISSING = 'FALSE' THEN 1 END) AS MISSINGFALSE,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN H.MATCHED = 'TRUE' THEN 1  END) AS MATCHEDTRUE
FROM   TBLREF T 
JOIN   TBLHISTORICAL H
ON     R.REF = H.REF
GROUP BY T.REF
```